# How can I get checkboxes to be arranged in a table structure instead of just vertically in Django?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a model with a MultiSelectField that I would like to appear on my form as a series of checkboxes. There are a lot of available options, so rather than display the checkboxes vertically, I would like to display them in 3 columns and 10 rows. I'm new to crispy forms and bootstrap but I think that would be the best way to go about it. How can I use them to accomplish this task?

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    accession_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    MEDICATION_CHOICES = (
        ('ACTIQ', 'ACTIQ'),
        ('HYDROCODONE/APAP', 'HYDROCODONE/APAP'),
        ('OXY IR', 'OXY IR'),
        ('ADDERALL', 'ADDERALL'),
        ('HYDROMORPHONE', 'HYDROMORPHONE'),
        ('PERCOCET', 'PERCOCET'),
        ('ALPRAZOLAM', 'ALPRAZOLAM'),
        ('KADIAN', 'KADIAN'),
        ('PREGABALIN', 'PREGABALIN'),
        ('MSIR', 'MSIR'),
        ('TRAMADOL', 'TRAMADOL'),
        ('ELAVIL', 'ELAVIL'),
        ('NEURONTIN', 'NEURONTIN'),
        ('TYLOX', 'TYLOX'),
        ('EMBEDA', 'EMBEDA'),
        ('NORCO', 'NORCO'),
        ('ULTRAM', 'ULTRAM'),
        ('ENDOCET', 'ENDOCET'),
        ('NORTRIPTYLINE', 'NORTRIPTYLINE'),
        ('VALIUM', 'VALIUM'),
        ('FENTANYL', 'FENTANYL'),
        ('NUCYNTA', 'NUCYNTA'),
        ('VICODIN', 'VICODIN'),
        ('FENTORA', 'FENTORA'),
        ('OPANA', 'OPANA'),
        ('VICOPROFEN', 'VICOPROFEN'),
        ('FLEXERIL', 'FLEXERIL'),
        ('OXECTA', 'OXECTA'),
        ('XANAX', 'XANAX'),
        ('GABAPENTIN', 'GABAPENTIN'),
        ('OXYCODONE', 'OXYCODONE'),
        ('ZOLPIDEM', 'ZOLPIDEM'),
        ('HYDROCODONE', 'HYDROCODONE'),
        ('OXYCONTIN', 'OXYCONTIN'),
    )
    medications = MultiSelectField(choices=MEDICATION_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
     accession_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}))
    medications = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=MEDICATION_CHOICES)
```

html

```
{% extends 'accessioning/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New Order</h2>
     <form method="POST" id="orderForm" data-physicians-url="{% url 'ajax_load_physicians' %}" novalidate>
     {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                {{ form.accession_id|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                {{ form.medications|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: @quicklikerabbit just added, thank you.